# Fluentd logging site activity options

Tags: logging, nginx, fluentd

I'm wanting to implement ***Fluentd*** to log everything from user actions to nginx logs.

We have 1 site that runs express (server side react)

- users login
- view content
- like content
- comment on content

Content can be an article, video, photo, etc...

We're using ***nginx*** to handle all the traffic & ssl. Users are authenticated with ***jwt*** tokens, the jwt tokens hold the userId, email, and name.

I was initially thinking of logging ***everything*** through by deconstructing requests using regexes and built in fluentd methods. But the thing is I'll have to decompile the ***JWT*** and grab the ***userId***.

But I'm thinking now it may be better to send http requests to the ***nginx*** host so fluentd picks them up with the corresponding tag(fluentd will be listening on all ports).

A request may look something like this:

```
{"activity": "liked", 
"contentId": "2", 
"contentSlug": "/some-path/slug-here", 
"userId": "44"} POST http://hostname.com/fluentd.tagname.here (this tag could be user.activity)
```

These requests will be added to some sort of queue, so that every X minutes,  a bulk update is made.

Note multiple requests will be created per site view. So along with the ***user activity***, a log for the content will be recorded which will include the id, time, etc...

Is what I've explained a good way of doing logging user activities? Should I send http requests from my web servers with information such as an activity that a user has performed?

Comment: I don't see a question here?
Are you simply asking 'Is this an approach that would work?' or are you looking for proposals for other implementations, or perhaps suggestions as wether FluentD will function well in this architecture?

Comment: Yeah I'm wanting to know whether it will work and whether it'd be an efficient way of logging everything . @TobyJackson